# SQL statement to update rows in a table, insert into/update same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a seemingly pretty simple situation here, but one which I have never dealt with. I have researched the issue and have found situations pretty similar, but not close enough to run on a production db.

I have 1 table with 2 columns. I want to find all entries that share the same  values in column 1, and update one of the rows' column 2. Please keep in mind that the example below is over-simplified. This is a large db with many rows in this table... i need to update a specific value in col_2 for one of the matching values in col_1.

```
For instance:

        col_1     col_2
        1111     green
        1111     blue
        2222     green
        2222     blue

    Becomes:
    col_1     col_2
    1111     green
    1111     red
    2222     green
    2222     red
```

From what I have gathered, something along the lines of an update statement but I'm at a loss for the logic of finding the matching values and updating only one of them. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 'updating only one ' - do you care which one? It doesn't seem from your example that col1 is important just update where col2 = blue

Comment: yes, value 'blue' needs to change to 'red'. Value 'green' needs to remain the same... (these are metaphoric stand-in values for the example fyi lol)

Comment: Col 1 is used as the unique identifier for each item in the db. Col_2 is the color. There are 2 entries in the table for each item/unique ID. I need to change the col_2 value of blue for each item to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `col2` values are unique for each `col1`, you can chose one using `join`:

```
update t join
       (select col1, max(col2) as max_col2
        from t
        group by col1
       ) tt
       on tt.col1  t.col1
    set col2 = 'red';
```

Comment: Thank you- just the type of functionality I was looking for. Yes the col_2 values are unique per each col_1. I ended up just doing it the long way by exporting lists into excel and formatting a super long "delete" then "insert" query, but this is super helpful, as I find myself needing to do this type of thing quite frequently... so I'm sure I'll be referring to this. I tested it and it does work by the way.